# How to delete all checked row of JqGrid MVC Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using MVC JqGrid Helper,Multiselect Column.and in the UI it appearing fine

I have Used .SetMultiSelect(true) and   .SetMultiBoxOnly(false) method of JqGrid MVC Helper DLL.
**View is as follow:**

```
 @(Html.Grid("AllCompany").SetCaption("Organizations")
.AddColumn(new Column("<input type=checkbox editable=true>").SetSortable(false).SetCustomFormatter("mvcJqGrid.demo.buttonize").SetWidth(10))
.AddColumn(new Column("OrganizationId").SetWidth(0).SetSearch(false).SetHidden(true))
 .AddColumn(new Column("Name").SetWidth(10).SetSearch(true))
 .AddColumn(new Column("Email").SetWidth(10).SetSearch(true))
.AddColumn(new Column("Address").SetWidth(10).SetSearch(true))
   .AddColumn(new Column("Phone").SetWidth(10).SetSearch(true))
    .AddColumn(new Column("Website").SetWidth(10).SetSearch(true))    
      .AddColumn(new Column("Action").SetSearch(false).SetCustomFormatter("mvcJqGrid.demo.buttonize").SetWidth(5))
      .SetUrl(Url.Action("Organization_List","Organization"))
        .SetRowNum(10)
        .SetAutoWidth(true)
        .SetRowList(new[] { 10, 15, 20, 50 })
        .SetViewRecords(true)
          .SetSearchToggleButton(true)
              .SetSearchClearButton(true)
         .SetPager("pager").SetWidth(50)
         .SetSearchToolbar(true)
         .SetMultiSelect(true)
    .SetMultiBoxOnly(false)
)
```

**and the Controller code is:**

```
public JsonResult Organization_List(GridSettings gridSettings)
        {
            Log.LogInfo(string.Format("Getting all the list of CompanyTeamplate"));
            List<tbl_organizations> OrgList =                        Organization_Services.Get_All_Organizations();

            List<tbl_organizations> pagedRecord = OrganizationService.Organization_List(gridSettings, OrgList);
            var templateList = pagedRecord.ToList();
            int totalTemplates = OrgList.Count;
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalTemplates / gridSettings.PageSize + 1,
                page = gridSettings.PageIndex,
                records = totalTemplates,
                rows = (
                        from tl in templateList
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = tl.OrganizationId,
                            cell = new[]
                            {  
                                tl.OrganizationId.ToString(),
                                tl.Name.ToString(),
                                tl.Email.ToString(),
                                tl.Address,
                               (tl.Phone!=null?tl.Phone:string.Empty).ToString(),
                                (tl.Website!=null?tl.Website:string.Empty).ToString()                                                    
                            }
                        }).ToArray()

            };
            Log.LogInfo(string.Format("Got all the list of CompanyTeamplate"));


            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

all the checkbox are displaying in first Column.and data fetching from JSON Method .

**Now i want to perform delete action of all selected checked row .`enter code here`
I have no idea how to do it in jqGrid helper MVC.**
Any Help will Appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: please provide your code.

Comment: Code has been edited,please help.

Comment: (not the actual solution, but might help)
In this example, the page posts the Json of the selected rows, http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridPostLocalDataToServer.htm
 Get the Ids and you can perform a deleted operation in your controller !